# Elastic nest accessing sub property of text type

Tags: elasticsearch, range, nest

I have created text property **name** also i have created sub property as **words_count of name** and i want to have range query on words_count of name. How can i access it in c# using Nest.

```
"mappings": {
"person": {
  "properties": {
    "name": { 
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": { 
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "words_count": { 
          "type": "token_count",
          "analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "length": { 
          "type": "token_count",
          "analyzer": "character_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

I have length of name but its from c# string length. I want access words_count sub property of name created in elastic.

```
c# code

Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<MyType>, QueryContainer> query = m => m
                                    .Range(r => r.Field(f => f.name.words_count).Relation(RangeRelation.Within)
                                    .GreaterThanOrEquals(10).LessThanOrEquals(14));
```

I want replacement for **f.name.words_count** from elastic nest. do i need to create class for name having property length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a POCO property to map to a [`multi-field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) (also often referred to as `fields` or `sub-fields`).

They are functionality to be able to index a single input in multiple different ways, which is very common for search use cases. For example, indexing a street address with multiple different types of analysis.

You can use the [`.Suffix(...)`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html#_complex_field_name_expressions) extension method to reference a `multi-field`

```cs
Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<MyType>, QueryContainer> query = m => m
    .Range(r => r
        .Field(f => f.name.Suffix("words_count"))
        .Relation(RangeRelation.Within)
        .GreaterThanOrEquals(10)
        .LessThanOrEquals(14)
    );
```